# Firebase how to add a Set and actual Name as key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Set of Usernames `{"Max", "Jane", "Joe"}`.
And I want to add this Set to my Firebase DB, but I can't get it working:

```
this.addedUsers.forEach((user: string) => {
       var gameUsersRef = firebase.database().ref("games").child("users").set({
                    user: 1
                });
});
```

But it adds of course the "user" in the query as key, which has to be unique.

```
(user: "Max")
```

Is there a Way to use a Number as Key which is raising as my forEach goes on? `(1: "Max")` - or even the userkey which is stored in my Database? `(*userkeyindb*: "Max")`

Answer (score 1):

use [push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) method to make new key and then set the value to the generated key

```
this.addedUsers.forEach((user: string) => {
       var gameUsersRef = firebase.database().ref("games").child("users").push();
       gameUsersRef.set(user);
});
```